# Использование button

Tags: html, button

Что лучше использовать для создания кнопки с дальнейшим редиректом? Упираться в семантику и использовать button или в быстродействие и расширенные возможности? 
Сори если несу ахинею)

Comment: Я не понял ничего. Для создания кнопки логично было бы использовать кнопку

Comment: Если Вам настолько важно быстродействие, что готовы отказаться от анимации кнопки в пользу простой ссылки - то я завидую такой нагрузке на ваш ресурс. Семантика баттона тут не при чем - просто вариант. Главная семантика редирректа - гиперссылка.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, буду все таки использовать button, просто на каких сайтах не гляну, очень часто юзают a/span.

Comment: Эм.. А что у button не так с быстродействием?

Answer (score 0):

"Что лучше использовать для создания кнопки с дальнейшим редиректом?"

Если `простой редирект`, то о чем речь..

```
<a href="#meaningful">ССЫЛКА!</a>
```

==========

Для передачи данных лучше `form` не встречал.

```
<form action="http://yandex.ru" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="ИМЯ КНОПКИ">
</form>
```

Выбирайте между METHOD, `POST`, `GET`.

`POST` скрытый, не кладет данные в адресную строку, а кладет в http заголовки.

`GET` кладет данные в адресную строку

Это способ если мы собираемся все данные полей вложенные в form передавать на другую страницу.

Варианты предложены без использования `JS`